# Imposing a threshold on values in dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following code:

```
t = 12
s = numpy.array(df.Array.tolist())
s[s<t] = 0
thresh = numpy.where(s>0, s-t, 0)
df['NewArray'] = list(thresh)
```

while it works, surely there must be a more pandas-like way of doing it.

**EDIT:**
`df.Array.head()` looks like this:

```
0    [0.771511552006, 0.771515476223, 0.77143569165...
1    [3.66720695274, 3.66722560562, 3.66684636758, ...
2    [2.3047433839, 2.30475510675, 2.30451676559, 2...
3    [0.999991522708, 0.999996609066, 0.99989319662...
4    [1.11132718786, 1.11133284052, 0.999679589875,...
Name: Array, dtype: object
```

Comment: Which bit specifically are you asking about wrt to `pandas`? I think `df['NewArray'] = np.where(df['Array'] < 12, 0, df['Array'] - 12)` would do it in a single liner

Comment: The whole morphing into numpy and lists, and then back again seems strange.

Comment: Well my comment should show that it's entirely unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can simply subtract and use [`clip_lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_lower.html):

```
In [29]: df["NewArray"] = (df["Array"] - 12).clip_lower(0)

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
   Array  NewArray
0     10         0
1     11         0
2     12         0
3     13         1
4     14         2
```

Comment: I get this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'`, as `df['Array']` is a list.

Comment: How can `df["Array"]` be a list?  Isn't `df` a `DataFrame`, and so `df["Array"]` is a `Series`?

Comment: I don't know how, I'm just assuming it is based on the error message. Maybe it's because the `df['Array']` is interpreted as an object. `df['Array']` is a list of arrays, such that `df['Array'][0]` returns a lists.

Comment: You keep saying `list`, but that sounds like `df["Array"]` is a Series, but you're storing lists instead of scalar values as elements in the Series -- which would explain why you have `dtype=object`. That isn't really supported by `pandas`.